# Importing swift files from one target to another

Tags: objective-c, swift, target, uiswitch

I have built a custom keyboard and using the app target I want some function to take place in my keyboard target. I'm using a `UISwitch` in the app. I'm currently using Objective C for my app but I can change it to swift. Please help me!

Regards,
Palash